# Fetching SAP-BW reports via an API

Tags: api, sap-bw

I'd like to fetch some SAP-BW reports programatically, but unfortunately my SAP collegues have no idea about how to do it. I'm no SAP expert either, but as a software-engineer I'm pretty confident that there is some API I could use with python or C# to fetch report data like this one when the user clicks on *Eport nach Excel*:

[image: example]

I'm not asking for any code, I'm sure I'd find something on GitHub, however I need to know what I should even look for. In other words could you point me to the right direction by showing me what documentation I need to read or maybe what technical terms are relevant for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this question is quite old but I am going to answer it anyway.

You need to turn the underlying query into an OData Gateway endpoint and then you can call the resulting gateway service from any application that supports HTTP calls.

I no longer have access to an SAP BW environment to show you step by step but many blogs have been written about it and although providing links is not really how we should be supplying answers, this is the best I can do for now.

https://blogs.sap.com/2019/02/19/how-to-do-odata-services-from-bex-query/

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BI/Steps+to+Create+an+ODATA+service+for+a+BW+Query

https://abap-blog.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/How-to-Create-OData-Services-for-Analytic-Queries.pdf

Comment: Old, but still unsolved. Now I'll know where to start and I'll be able to perform some experiments ;-D

Comment: I was surprised it hadn’t been answered so glad I could help. Have had to do this many times and it definitely works. My one tip is, rename your restricted and calculated key figures in your query if you want useful names, otherwise you get the guid’s.